# Wordpress custom post type list page large database

Tags: php, wordpress

the custom post list page(where all posts are listed) is giving
**Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded** error,

Increasing time to an extent gived the same result i.e. maximum execution time reached or memory allocation error

I have

1. No plugin activated,
2. wordpress default theme activated for debugging purposes

   and still getting the same error

What I observed is for some reason wordpress is trying to show all custom posts(25,000 +) on the list page rather than showing 20 posts and than paginate the others, as no plugin is activated I am not sure what could be the reason behind this.

Is there any way I can observer what is causing this, I have added wp_debug to true in wp-config.php

Any help on this will be appreciated the custom post type have more than 25,000 posts

Comment: Is it a [hierarchical post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_hierarchical)?

Comment: yes its hierarchical type i.e. hierarchical is set to true

Comment: @PieterGoosen I am referring to wp-admin (not front end) I am unable to see any qp-query

Comment: Please see the [Arguments section of register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments). I quote: "Be careful, when choosing [hierarchical] for your custom post type - if you are planning to have many entries (say - over 100), you will run into memory issue. With this parameter set to true WordPress will fetch all entries of that particular post type, together with all meta data, on each administration page load for your post type."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments). Quite simply, this is a symptom of WordPress fetching all "hierarchical" posts, along with their meta data:

> Be careful, when choosing it for your custom post type - if you are
>   planning to have many entries (say - over 100), you will run into
>   memory issue. With this parameter set to true WordPress will fetch all
>   entries of that particular post type, together with all meta data, on
>   each administration page load for your post type.

The problem comes from the fact that, in order to display pages and their hierarchy, WP has to load all of them and then build the tree in memory.

Comment: Thank you @mevius ... I missed the hierarchical part